# SwiftUI: filename of dropped item using dropDestination(for:action:)

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop

I have a SwiftUI app that allows PDFs to be dragged and dropped from Finder using `dropDestination(for:action:)`. While reading the PDFs is successful, I cannot access the file's name. How can I obtain the filename?

```swift
  Text("Drop PDFs here")
    .dropDestination(for: Data.self) { items, location in
      for item in items {
        if let document = PDFDocument(data: item) {
          // let filename = ...? How do I get the document's filename?
          pdfs.append(document)
        }
      }
      return pdfs.count >= 1
    }
```

Comment: use ```document.write(to: URI)```in order to store the pdf whereever you want. You can declare the filename and path by yourself (e.g. by using a counter)

Comment: Thank you @mihema, but that wasn't my question. I need access to the file name of the dropped file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, ok. I misunderstood.

From documentation:

> The dropped content can be provided as binary data, file URLs, or file promises.

The docs offer this piece of code:

```
@State private var isDropTargeted = false

var body: some View {
    Color.pink
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
        .dropDestination(for: String.self) { receivedTitles, location in
            animateDrop(at: location)
            process(titles: receivedTitles)
        } isTargeted: {
            isDropTargeted = $0
        }
}

func process(titles: [String]) { ... }
func animateDrop(at: CGPoint) { ... }
```

Perhaps you can use `ÙRL.self` instead of `String.self` or String.self offers the filename.

Comment: Using URL.self was the solution indeed. That gives you the URL of the dragged file, instead of its contents.